# Unexpected StackOverflowError in KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, event-listener, stack-overflow

I am writing a program that can write sets of questions for review to a file for another program to read.  The possible answers are typed into JTextFields at the bottom.  It has code to ensure that there won't bew more than one blank JTextField at the end.  When I type in answers, at varying points it will throw a StackOverflowError.

The stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:232)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:232)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:232)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:232)
```

and the code:  now shortened!!!

```
package writer;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener
{
    private MutableQuestion current;
    private WriterPanel writer;
    private JPanel top=new JPanel(new BorderLayout()),answerPanel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    private JSplitPane split;
    private JTextField title=new JTextField();
    private JTextArea question=new JTextArea();
    private ArrayList<JTextField> answers=new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    public MyPanel()
    {
    super(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(title,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        split=new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,true,new JScrollPane(question),new JScrollPane(answerPanel));
    split.setDividerLocation(150);
    this.add(split,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    answers.add(new JTextField());
    answerPanel.add(answers.get(0));
    answers.get(0).addKeyListener(this);
}
private void back(){}
private void fitTitle(){}
private void fixAnswers()
{
    //System.out.println(answers);
    while(answers.get(answers.size()-1).getText().equals("")&&answers.size()>1&&answers.get(answers.size()-2).getText().equals(""))
        removeAnswer(answers.size()-1);
    if(!answers.get(answers.size()-1).getText().equals(""))
    {
        answers.add(new JTextField());
        answerPanel.add(answers.get(answers.size()-1));
        answers.get(answers.size()-2).removeKeyListener(this);
        //answers.get(answers.size()-1);
        answerPanel.revalidate();
    }
    answers.get(answers.size()-1).addKeyListener(this);
}
private void removeAnswer(int i){}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
{
    fixAnswers();
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
public void newQuestion(){}
public void loadQuestion(int i){}
public void saveQuestion(){}
public void loadQuestion(MutableQuestion q){}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame j=new JFrame();
    j.setSize(600,600);
    j.add(new MyPanel());
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    j.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Way too much code.. (http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I know, What do you think would be the best way to shorten it for the question?

Comment: `while (answers.get(answers.size() - 1).getText().equals("") && answers.size() > 1 && answers.get(answers.size() - 2).getText().equals("")) {
            removeAnswer(answers.size() - 1);
        }`  I don't know what that does, but it seems fundamentally flawed.  Whatever that logic is, I would put it in its own method if only to look at in a new light.

Comment: That part removes blank text fields at the end.  There are three parts to the condition.  The first is that the last field is blank.  The second is that there is more than one field, so the next part won't go out of bounds.  The third condition is that the second to last field is blank.  This ensures that you don't have more than 1 blank field at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you type a key your initial listener's (this') keyTyped method is called, that calls fixAnswers, and as the last step, it adds another listener to your JTextField.  You never remove any listeners so eventually you have a longer string of them than the Java stack can handle.

You only need one listener.  Don't keep adding them and I suspect your problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite recursions in `AWTEventMulticaster` are usually caused by you adding a component inside itself. I cannot see how that may happen from the code you've pasted, but the bug might be in other parts of your code.

See [What causes an endless recursion in AWTEventMulticaster.mouseEntered()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090775/what-causes-an-endless-recursion-in-awteventmulticaster-mouseentered).

Comment: I checked my code, the only things with key listeners are JTextFields and JTextAreas

Answer (score -1):

A piece of advice the next time you post a question: provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). If we now wanted to run your code, we had to fix a bunch of compile errors due to missing classes and provide a main method ourself. The `WriterPanel` class seems to be completely unrelated to the error.

Further, strip down your code. You already came to the conclusion that the error was in the `fixAnswers` method. Then there is no need to provide us with code for the `top` panel and for the `question`. See below for a stripped down version which can reproduce the problem. Uncomment that one line to fix the error.

```
package writer;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SetPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
  private JPanel answerPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout( 0, 1 ) );
  private ArrayList<JTextField> answers = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

  public SetPanel(  ) {
    super( new BorderLayout() );
    this.add( new JScrollPane( answerPanel ), BorderLayout.CENTER );
    answers.add( new JTextField() );
    answerPanel.add( answers.get( 0 ) );
    answers.get( 0 ).addKeyListener( this );
  }

  private void fixAnswers() {
    while ( answers.get( answers.size() - 1 ).getText().equals( "" ) && answers.size() > 1 && answers.get( answers.size() - 2 ).getText().equals( "" ) )
      removeAnswer( answers.size() - 1 );
    if ( !answers.get( answers.size() - 1 ).getText().equals( "" ) ) {
      answers.add( new JTextField() );
      answerPanel.add( answers.get( answers.size() - 1 ) );
      answers.get( answers.size() - 2 ).removeKeyListener( this );
      answerPanel.revalidate();
    }
//    answers.get( answers.size() - 1 ).removeKeyListener( this );
    answers.get( answers.size() - 1 ).addKeyListener( this );
  }

  private void removeAnswer( int i ) {
    answers.remove( i );
    answerPanel.remove( i );
    answerPanel.revalidate();
  }

  @Override
  public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e ) {
  }

  @Override
  public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e ) {
    fixAnswers();
  }

  @Override
  public void keyReleased( KeyEvent e ) {

  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame testFrame = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );
        testFrame.add( new SetPanel() );
        testFrame.pack();
        testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        testFrame.setVisible( true );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll get started